# How Can I Make My JS Search Bar Be NOT Case Sensitive?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, case-sensitive

So I have created a web-site to which you can upload, download, delete and preview files. I also have a java-script function that lets the user search through the files. Only thing is, that the search is case sensitive. Can anyone help me with a sample code on how should I change my script so that it will NOT be case sensitive anymore? I am very new to ASP.NET and still trying to wrap my head around.

Here is the Index page:

```
@model IEnumerable<Proiect2PracticaClona.Models.Files>

<center>
    <h1>Daca nici acu nu merge ... ma sinucid</h1>
    <h2>Sa moara mama</h2>
    <hr />
    @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))

    {
        <form methord="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
            <input type="file" name="fifile" />
            @Html.RadioButton("category", "incepator")
            @Html.RadioButton("category", "intermediar")
            @Html.RadioButton("category", "admin")
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />



            <hr />
        </form>}
    <div>
        File Name:<input id="search"  onkeyup="search()" placeholder="cauta"/>

    </div>

    <table class="table">
        @if (User.IsInRole("User"))
        {
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link">Incepatori <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link">Avansati</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">

                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled">Admini</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </nav>
        }
        <tr>
            <th>File Name</th>

        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.info</td>
                <td><a href="@Url.Action("Download","Home",new { filename=item.info })">Download</a></td>
                @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    <td><a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Home", new { filedel = item.info })">Delete</a></td>
                }
                <td><a href="/Home/DocumentViewer/@item.info">Viewer</a></td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    @section scripts
{
        <script>
            function search() {
                $("tr").each(function (index, value) {
                    if (index > 0 && !$(this).find("td")[0].innerText.includes($("#search").val())) {
                        $(this).attr("hidden", true);
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeAttr("hidden");
                    }
                    console.log(value);
                })
            }
        </script>
    }
</center>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not convert both sides to lowercase when checking. This case it does not matter what the casing of element in td block is and what is the case of text inserted by user.
We use this a lot in out application to make comparisons.

```
function search() {
                $("tr").each(function (index, value) {
                    if (index > 0 && !$(this).find("td")[0].innerText.toLowerCase().includes($("#search").val().toLowerCase())) {
                        $(this).attr("hidden", true);
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeAttr("hidden");
                    }
                    console.log(value);
                })
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works flawlessly, love you

Answer (score 2):

Case sensitivity can be negated by transforming the value on either side of the query to lowercase or to uppercase (according to your preference.

So your search logic needs to change from

```
if (index > 0 && !$(this).find("td")[0].innerText.includes($("#search").val())) {
```

To this:

```
if (index > 0 && !$(this).find("td")[0].innerText.toLowerCase().includes($("search").val().toLowerCase())) {
```